# UITableView grouped section footer not updating after reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 3 or 2 sections (depending on datasource), in my grouped UITableView. I am trying to reload the last section via:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
                [feedDetailTB reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:feedDetailTB.numberOfSections-1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            }];
        });
```

[image]

First of all, the footer never disappears. The data source basically keeps track of whether there are more comments or not (a simple load more functionality). In the `viewForFooterInSection` I simply `return nil`, when all the comments have been loaded.

But, as you see in the GIF, at first the `loading` button stays there. It is even accessible and works. When I scroll up, it vanishes and one can see it in the bottom, which is correct. But after all the comments have been reloaded, it should vanish, but sadly it stays there.

If I use `reloadData` it works fine. But I can't used it, since I have other sections, which I don't need to reload.

Second, there is a weird animation/flickering of the row items, even when I have used `UITableViewRowAnimationNone`. Not visible in the GIF

Comment: "View old comments" is a footer view? it looks like you are replacing the text of it with "loading". Can you update the post with code where you show "View old comments"

Comment: @SantosRamón It is a footer view, and yes I am updating its text. But the issue is `reloadSections` does not call view for footer, and hence the footer is not reoaded with appropriate data source

Comment: You need to rework this question. Essentially you're asking us to troubleshoot a problem and we don't know what you've done. It looks like you're incorrectly updating the tableview, but without the code and more detail one will never know.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement "isTheLastSection" according to your logic

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (isTheLastSection) {
         return 40;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I already have a check. Regardless, I dont need the "load more" button to disappear for last section. I want it to disappear for last section, when there are no more comments pending. For that I have a variable, which keeps track of this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add new rows to a section, you must use the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` rather than just adding new objects to data source and reloading a section.

Here's the code:

```
NSMutableArray *newCommentsIndexPath = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                for (NSInteger i = currentCount; i < (_postDetailDatasource.commentsFeedInfo.allCommentsArray.count + serverComments.count); i ++)
                {
                    NSIndexPath *idxPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:sectionNumber];

                    [newCommentsIndexPath addObject:idxPath];
                }

                [_postDetailDatasource.commentsFeedInfo.allCommentsArray addObjectsFromArray:serverComments];

                [feedDetailTB beginUpdates];

                [feedDetailTB insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newCommentsIndexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

                [feedDetailTB endUpdates];
```