# tableView section headers disappear SWIFT

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, header, nsindexpath

I have a tableView set up so that when a cell is touched, it expands in height to reveal more information.  The tableView has 5 sections.

I have a bug: when a cell expands, all headersCells below that cell go invisible.  The console outputs the following: "[31233:564745] no index path for table cell being reused"

In my storyboard I have 2 custom cells : `"myCell"` for the data bearing cells, and `"headerCell"` for the headers.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

   let thisGoal : GoalModel = goalArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]


    if self.currentPath != nil && self.currentPath == indexPath  {
        self.currentPath = nil
    } else {
        self.currentPath = indexPath
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

If I enter `tableView.reloadData()` in between the begin/end updates, it functions properly, although the header background turns black, and loses animation.

I have all of the stuff for headers declared in: `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?`

what am I missing?  I'd really like the tableView to still have animations, and keep the background `clearColor()`.

Thanks in advance.  I did read through the objective C answers, but couldn't get them to work for me.  I'd really appreciate some SWIFT help.

I think the problem is the no index path for table cell being reused.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

I found an answer in the console output. Use this code in the header function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

Do not return your `headerCell`, or your reusable identifier. Return the `reuseIdentifier.contentView`. For me it's: `return headerCell!.contentView`.

Comment: I get transparent header view in such case.

Comment: What if you want to add buttons or gestures to the cell? It won't work, 'cause `contentView` won't know anything about it.

Comment: yeah it doesnt work if i have a button... did you find a solution for this eMdOS?

Comment: All my views go invisible when I return header.contentView

Comment: Add tap gesture on contentView not on cell/view iteself, then it will work.

Comment: Thanks for solving my issue, but can someone explain why it was happening?

Comment: The alternative is to create your own label in your custom cell subclass and that way you can return the view instead of the content view

Comment: Hahaha. It worked. Can't believe but it worked. Screw Apple.

Comment: Returning content view removed my formatting of cell i.e corner radius. Any solution ?

Comment: I'll use a custom UIView inside the cell and put all the controls/other views in it instead of the cell. And use that custom UIView as the header.

Answer (score 19):

Just to add, I was baffled for WAY longer than I should have been as to why I couldn't refer to the contentView of my cell, when I could quite clearly see it was there. My custom class (using UITableViewCell rather than UITableViewHeaderFooterView) would return a fatal error each time. Therefore make sure any custom styling is setup under UITableViewHeaderFooterView class like:

```
class CustomHeaderCell: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
```

You will also need to register the resuableIdentifer like this:

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "HeaderCell", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "CellHeader")
```

Then this bad boy:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("CellHeader") as! CustomHeaderCell!
    return headerCell!.contentView
}
```

Comment: no need to add UITableViewHeaderFooterView if the class is extended in UITableViewController. thank you for the headerCell!.contentView answer

Comment: It is not compulsory to use UITableViewHeaderFooterView, I am using UITableViewCell class but the key was to return the cell.contentView rather the cell itself. Returning the whole cell was causing the issue for me.

Comment: adding .contentView saved my day

Comment: This is the best answer! Never make your headers like a cells guys!

Answer (score 11):

Since I'm not at 50 reputation yet, I can't comment on the previous answer, so I apologize for listing this as another answer.

Returning the ContentView will make the function work but will remove all formatting done to the reuseIdentifier (headerCell)

```
headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
```

This will NOT provide a Cyan color to your headerCell

To fix this, just add the ".contentView" to your formatting lines

```
headerCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
```

Answer (score 5):

Table view headers in 2 tables disappeared when I converted my app to IOS 10  - I found the reason in Apple developer API documentation on table headers. When I added the following, the missing headers reappeared!

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
return 44 // where 44 is the header cell view height in my storyboard
}
```

Comment: This seems to only be the case in iOS 10, not necessary in 11/12

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap the `TableViewCell` inside an `UIView`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
  let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 50)) // 50 = Header height

  guard let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyHeaderView") as? MyHeaderView else { fatalError(" Failed to load MyHeaderView") }
  headerCell.frame = containerView.bounds
  containerView.addSubview(headerCell)

  return containerView
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same bug because I was returning a cell using dequeue method instead of a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.

### Solution:

- Add a view outside of the view hierarchy
- Set the type to `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`
- Customize
- Link to an `@IBOutlet`
- In `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` return the outlet

#### Common pitfalls:

Don't forget to set the header sizes
Don't forget to set the outlet as strong.