# Reload only one section header in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I'm using a custom cell as a section header in my `UITableView`. In that cell there are three buttons. If any of the buttons are clicked in that section's cell, it should reload that custom section cell only, not any rows. Is this possible?

I was using the following code to reload that cell:

```
tableViewHome.reloadSections([1], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
```

It's hiding my section cell and distorting my entire table.

**UPDATE**

I'm using `UITableView` and following code I'm using:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let cellHeader = tableViewHome.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "header") as! HeaderTableViewCell

        cellHeader.filter1btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(filterBtnAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cellHeader.filter2Btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(filterBtnAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cellHeader.filter3btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(filterBtnAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)


        return cellHeader
    }


    @IBAction func filterBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        print(sender.tag)

        tableViewHome.reloadSections([1], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)



    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a little unclear as to what's going on here, but it sounds like there is a `UITableView` concepts worth explaining here:

`UITableView` has its own concept of a cell, implemented as [`UITableViewCell`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell), and its own concept of a header/footer, implemented as [`UITableViewHeaderFooterView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewheaderfooterview).

Depending on which of these two you meant, there are a few things you can do to get the intended effect:

#### The `UITableViewCell` Approach:

If you're using a `UITableViewCell` as the first row of a section to act like a "header," and you just want to reload that row to the exclusion of the rest of the section, you can call `yourTableViewInstance.reloadRows(at:with:)` [(Apple Documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows) This method takes an array of `IndexPath`s, and an animation style. You can pass in the indexPath of the one you want to reload.

#### The `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` Approach:

If you're using a proper `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` then you need to make sure that you're providing the appropriate view when reloading the section. [Zack Shapiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/602210/zack-shapiro) outlines the steps you need to take in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43287008/224988):

1. Create a class that's a subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.
2. Register it with your `UITableView` instance.
3. Then in `viewForHeaderInSection`, you do `let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "HeaderView") as! YourHeaderViewSubclass`

The last thing he points out is this:

> The deceptive thing is the function calls for a return of `UIView?` when it really needs a `dequeuedReusableHeaderFooterView` or `reloadData` will cause it to disappear.

It depends on which of these two implementation paths you're taking, but this should be enough information to point you in the right direction.

### Edit:

Based on the code you added, it looks like you're calling [`yourTableViewInstance.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecell) instead of [`yourTableViewInstance.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614975-dequeuereusableheaderfooterview) inside of `viewForHeaderInSection`.

You need to have a subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and then call it correctly. Create that new subclass, then change this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let cellHeader = tableViewHome.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "header") as! HeaderTableViewCell

   // ...
```

to this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let cellHeader = tableViewHome.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "header") as! HeaderTableView

   // ...
```

You need to follow two steps here:

1. Create a new class, subclassing `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` instead of `UITableViewCell`.
2. Then use the appropriate class as outlined above.

Comment: I updated my question, kindly see once again. Thank you

Comment: Updated to reflect. Looks like you're mixing up the cell and the header/footer view. On the right track, but almost there!

Comment: Hello, Sorry for late replying, well, if i use `yourTableViewInstance.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier:)` then i can't access the buttons, if it is possible then any help will be appreciable. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i made that. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you work out the issue with button interactivity?

Comment: Yes, I have used delegates for that, it is working perfectly now.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. It seems the answer matches doesn't match the question although it does match what the OP wants.

Specifically, the question is how to reload a single/specific Header cell. The answer points out the "right" way of using `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`, but does not answer how to reload a single/specific header using that approach. I'm supposing the goal is to find `reloadSectionIndexTitles()` but for a single section. [Although Apple's documentation says 
"Reloads the items in the index bar along the right side of the table view."
which is confusing.]

Comment: This answer does not address the question even indirectly. As confusing as its acceptance by the OP is that individual's follow up answer claiming his own solution to the problem - which also doesn't solve the stated problem.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, It is.

Let's say that this is implementation of your method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let customCell = .... as! YourCustomCell 
    customCell.someLabel.text = "Some Data"
    //... filling your curstom cell
    return customCell
}
```

You can change it in this way

```
func updateHeaderView(headerView:YourCustomCell, section: Int) {
    customCell.someLabel.text = "Some Data"
    //... filling your curstom cell  
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let customCell = .... as! YourCustomCell 
    self.updateHeaderView(customCell, section)
    return customCell
}
```

And call again `self.updateHeaderView(customCell, section)` whenever you want, e.g.

```
func buttonClicked() {
   let customCell = self.tableView.headerView(forSection: 0) as! YourCustomCell
   self.updateHeaderView(customCell, 0)
}
```

Comment: In `let customCell = tableViewHome.headerView(forSection: 0) as! HeaderTableViewCell` it says
`Cast from 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView?' to unrelated type 'HeaderTableViewCell' always fails`

Answer (score 2):

I think your header view class is extending UITableViewHeaderFooterView class. Add a function in the extension

```
extension UITableViewHeaderFooterView{
     func reloadHeaderCell(){
        preconditionFailure("This method must be overridden")
    }
}
```

Now override this in your Header class as below

```
class HeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
   override func reloadHeaderCell() {
      ////// add your logic to reload view
    }
}
```

Now you can simply call below line to refresh views

```
self.tableView?.headerView(forSection:0)?.reloadHeaderCell()
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did and working very correctly, Please follow the given answer:

**SWIFT 3.1**

Step 1:

Firstly I took a `view` xib, designed that according to my requirement and did register in my required class.

Secondly, did sub class `class HeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView` of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`

Like following image:

[image]

In my required class(here homeclass) I did register my `xib` file for my tableview.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableViewHome.register(UINib(nibName: "HeaderView", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "HeaderView")
}
```

Step 2:

Then in my required class i did following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let cellHeader = tableViewHome.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "HeaderView") as! HeaderView
        cellHeader.filterAction(cellHeader.filter1Btn)


        return cellHeader
    }
```

And it started working as per my requirement, later i added custom delegate for more actions in my class, but by subviewing, its now working.