# Issues with drawing a line during tableview reload

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, drawing

I have a tableview. I reload a section. My sectionheader has a line that requires to be drawn. 
The positioning of this line and how it’s drawn is based on contentview’s frame

1. If if do `tableview.reloadData()` it get’s drawn correctly. Tableview header’s frame is non-zero
2. If I do `notesTable.reloadSections([1], with: .automatic)` it *doesn’t* get drawn correctly. Tableview header’s frame is zero! 
   ( I need to use `reloadSections` because I want to animate it. `reloadData()` doesn’t give any animation)

so a very watered down example of my `viewForHeaderInSection` is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    // some code
     sectionView.setupUI()
    return sectionView
}
```

**Header class:**

```
class SectionHeaderclass: UITableViewHeaderFooterView{
    func setupUI(){
        let triangleViewArea = ViewWithTriangleLine(triangleCenter:Double(contentView.frame.width - 30))
    }
}
```

‍ `contentView.frame.width` returns `0` if I animate the section reload. Why?! How can I fix this?

Comment: after reloading with animation did you tried taking your drawing method under DispatchQueue.main,async {}

Comment: @iOSGeek the line is draw from the the draw rect override...

Comment: call this func setupUI() in Main queue after reloading, I assume func setupUI() is used to draw that line right ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update header, and it has some drawing view, its better you call `setNeedsDisplay()` on headerView instead of reloading tableview.
Note that `reloadSections(...)` updates cells in the sections not the header view.

Comment: dadash: I have to update the entire section.So reloading the header only isn't an option.The entire section needs to get reloaded + the line needs to get drawn correctly in the header. I've already seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658121/uitableview-reloadsections-reloaddata-header-view-becomes-blank/28056161?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). I'm dequeueing/registering my header correctly. If I scroll down till the header goes off screen and then bring it back. The line is drown. It just seems that the frame isn't drawn during animation.